# Confirmation page

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have 10 dropdown menus that are like:

```
Please Select
    Item 1
    Item 2
    Item 3
---Appetizers---
    Item 4
    Item 5
---Main Courses---
    Item 6
    Item 7
---Lunch Specials---
    Item 8
```

I want to grab the value if an Item is selected and print it on a confirmation page. Can I do that with a for loop and javascript? Like if I do this, how would I call it in HTML?

```
    function getItems() {
        var items = [
            document.getElementById("item1").value, 
            document.getElementById("item2").value,
            document.getElementById("item3").value,
            document.getElementById("item4").value,
            document.getElementById("item5").value,
            document.getElementById("item6").value,
            document.getElementById("item7").value,
            document.getElementById("item8").value,
            document.getElementById("item9").value,
            document.getElementById("item10").value
        ];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var count = 0;
            if (
                (item[i] != "Please Select") || 
                (item[i] != "---Appetizers---") || 
                (item[i] != "---Main Courses---") || 
                (item[i] != "---Lunch Specials---")
                ) {
                    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = item[i];
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The dropdowns are populated from a MySQL database using php. My HTML/php:

```
Item 4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <select id="item4">
            <option value"">Please Select</option>
            <?php if ($resultApp4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                <option value"">---Appetizers---</option>               
                <?php while($row = $resultApp4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
                <?php } } ?>
                <?php if ($resultMain4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                <option value"">---Main Courses---</option>                 
                <?php while($row = $resultMain4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
                            <br>
                <?php } } ?>
                <?php if ($result4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                <option value"">---Lunch Specials---</option> 

                <?php while($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
                            <br>
                <?php } } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML markup as well? Are `Item 1` `Item 2` etc part of option tag inside a select tag?

Comment: You should your _values to be tested with_ in array as well...

Comment: @AbhasTandon Yes - I just added my HTML to the OP.

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple items to be selected and output? If so, even multiple main courses?

Comment: still not fully able to understand your html markup with your php code. I guess using class name with select tags should help. Try the code in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6vje5bo/ If you have different try reproducing the same by editing this fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to generate a single drop down with all options. If that is intended, then make it one in which multiple selections can be made, which is not the default behaviour. For that to happen, add the `multiple` attribute to the `select`.

Then you need to add a listener to the `change` event, so that your code executes whenever the user selects or unselects item(s).

Note that you have forgotten some `=` after the `value` attributes. Also, it is not allowed to put a `<br>` tag after an `option` element. A `select` element should only have `option` children elements.

Here is how the corrected PHP could look:

```
Item 4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<select id="item4" multiple size="8">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
<?php if ($resultApp4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <option value="">---Appetizers---</option>               
    <?php while($row = $resultApp4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
<?php if ($resultMain4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <option value="">---Main Courses---</option>                 
    <?php while($row = $resultMain4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
<?php if ($result4->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <option value="">---Lunch Specials---</option> 
    <?php while($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['name']; ?> - $<?php echo $row['price']?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

The JavaScript could be much simpler, as in this working snippet:

```js
// Listen to the selection changes made:
document.querySelector('#item4').addEventListener('change', function () {
    // For this demo, the text is stored in a DIV
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = 
        [...this.selectedOptions] // convert selected options list to array
            .filter ( option => option.value.length ) // option must have a value
            .map( option => option.textContent ) // get text of option
            .join('\n'); // add line breaks
});
```

```html
Item 4 (hold Ctrl key to add selections)<br>
<select id="item4" multiple size=8>
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="">---Appetizers---</option>               
    <option value="1">drink 1 - $1</option>
    <option value="1.10">drink 2 - $1.10</option>
    <option value="">---Main Courses---</option>                 
    <option value="15">dish 1 - $15</option>
    <option value="16">dish 2 - $16</option>
    <option value="">---Lunch Secials---</option>                 
    <option value="10">lunch 1 - $10</option>
    <option value="11">lunch 2 - $11</option>
</select>
<div id="output" style="white-space:pre"></div>
```

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you accept it or leave a comment?